# How to modify button output after printing the screen (R shiny)?

Tags: r, shiny, output

I put a button in my shiny app, which download a table (called "tableau_final"), that i created in my code.

Howevever, when i print (on paper) the window of my app, i can see that my downloading button has sessions informations.

Is there a way to delete the session informations and just to see the download button like on the shiny app?

[download button with session informations after printing the app window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ1XK.png)

My code is pretty basic :

```
output$Download_Tableau.xlsx <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste(input$type, ".xlsx", sep = "")
  },
  content = function(file){
    fname <- paste(file,"xlsx",sep=".")
    wb <- loadWorkbook(fname, create = TRUE)
    createSheet(wb, name = "Detail")
    writeWorksheet(wb,  tableau_final, sheet = "Detail")
    saveWorkbook(wb)
    file.rename(fname,file)
  }
)
```